# JavaScript regex to check URL with possible wildcard subdomain specifier

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a simple JavaScript regex that will validate all of the following

```
http://example.com
https://example.com
example.com
*.example.com
https://example.com
http://*.example.com
https://*.example.com
```

*I use .com here by way of example but it could well be something else*

**but not**, for example, `https://*example.com`.  I thought the following

```
/((https?:\/\/)?([*]\.)?[a-z0-9_-]+(\.[a-z0-9_-]+)+\.?)/gi
```

might do the trick.  It does, almost.  The trouble is it passes `http://*example.com'.  I fail to see why this is happening.  Admittedly, regexes are not quite my forte.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the following should work:

```
^((?:https?:\/\/)?(?:\*\.)?[\w.-]+)$
```

This works for the [given test cases](https://regex101.com/r/hX8fK3/1).